# Is there a way to know `preview` window opened(existed) in vim?

Tags: vim

In fact, I just want to write a script to toggle `preview` window. But it seems can't archived from any internal setting of vim.

So, as title. I want to write a script to do it. Any one knows how to check `preview` window is opened(or existed)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check variable `previewwindow` or `pvw`(please refer to the [link](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27pvw%27)). A sample code would be:

```
fun! previewWindowOpened
    for nr in range(1, winnr('$'))
        if getwinvar(nr, "&pvw") == 1
            " found a preview
            return 1
        endif  
    endfor
    return 0
endfun
```

Comment: How can you know **&pvw** of 'getwinvar(nr,"&pvw")' ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `%w` to your  `statusline` config to get it to say `[Preview]` for the relevant window.

sample status line setting (in vimrc)

```
set statusline=%.50F%m%r\ %y\%w\ buffer\ %n\ %l\|%c\ [%p%%]
```

see `:h statusline` for more info